# Convert string to JSON stringformat

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing

I have a string where the object name is separated by dot from the field name as follows:

`{\"person.firstName\":\"Ahmed\",\"person.job\":\"Doctor\",\"products.packName\":\"antibiotic\",\"products.packSize\":\"large\"}}";`

I want to parse it to look like the json format:

`"{\"person\": {\"firstName\":\"Ahmed\",\"job\":\"Doctor\",},\"products\": {\"packName\":\"antibiotic\",\"packSize\":\"large\"}}";`

Is there an efficient algorithm for that?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Welcome to SO. We want to see some effort. We also want to know what version of JS you mean. For example here is a plain JS version, which would need a polyfill for older IEs due to the forEach

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/cLd865gy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is help for you.

```
    var str='{\"person.firstName\":\"Ahmed\",\"person.job\":\"Doctor\",\"products.packName\":\"antibiotic\",\"products.packSize\":\"large\"}';
var newObj={}
var json=JSON.parse(str);
for (i in json) {
    var splt=i.split('.');
    var key=splt[0];
    var subkey=splt[1];
    if(!(key in newObj)) {
        newObj[key]={};
    }
    newObj[key][subkey]=json[i];

}
//if you need string use str or not use newObj
var str=JSON.stringify(newObj);
console.log(str);
console.log(newObj);
console.log(newObj.person);
console.log(newObj.person.firstName);
console.log(newObj.person.job);
```

Comment: `if(!(key in newObj)) {
        newObj[key]={};
    }` is a waste of space and test. Since you are not handling nested keys, you do not need this test at all since `newObj[key][subkey]=json[i];` will overwrite any existing object

Answer (score 0):

Assuming left side may have multiple dots

```
let parsedObj = JSON.parse(<..YOUR STRINGIFIED JSON..>);

let myObj = {};
Object.keys(parsedObj).forEach((key) => {
    let val = parsedObj[key];
    let subKeys = key.split(".");
    let currentRef = myObj;
    subKeys.forEach((subKey, idx) => {
        if(idx === subKeys.length - 1) {
            currentRef[subKey] = val;
        } else {
            currentRef[subKey] = currentRef[subKey] || {};
            currentRef = currentRef[subKey];
        }
    });
});

let finalString = JSON.stringify(myObj);
```

P.S. Your string seems to contain an extra `}` in the end

Comment: @mplungjan what else do you suggest ? `currentRef` is the same variable used for deeper level assignments to the result. `currentRef = currentRef[subKey];` is what helps using same variable at different depths.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Apologies